# Python typing in other languages besides English

Tags: python, string, automation

I am trying to use python to simulate typing in other languages like Japanese but I don't know how I can do it without the end result shows "??????" can anyone help me with this?
here's my code

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
x = 0
time.sleep(1)

keyboard.type("こんにちは")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check which encoding if used to save your script and try something similar (be sure to write also the commented coding line):

```
# coding: utf-8
jap_word1 = u'中山'
jap_word2 = u'小倉'

print (jap_word1)
print (jap_word2)
```

So, adapted to your code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
x = 0
time.sleep(1)

keyboard.type(u"こんにちは")
```

Comment: I am glad it helped!
Please don't forget to upvote and / or choose the my answer as the correct one.